# How to get upper and lower data where time difference is more than 1 hour in mysql..?

Tags: mysql

I have a table having per hour table records like this :

[image]

As you can see every record have 1 hour difference but the highlighted one has more than one hour. I need a query which should return me both values upper (`id 11379728`) and lower (`id 11378448`) where gap is more than 1 hour.

Any help will be appreciated.

Note :- please ignore last datetime column as it serves different purpose.

Comment: May I suggest you add a minimal table DDL statement (so the answers can use those terms and it is easier to compare those? In that case you can leave out eg. the irrelevant rightmost datetime column etc. and maybe even provide at least 4 of those lines as insert statement? For the latter I'ld suggest lines 3,4,5, and 6 in your table and say only first and second column. Ok? I would think, this helps those, that are willing to answer. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I got a working solution (perfect in my case) :

```
SET @lastDate := (SELECT dateColumn FROM table ORDER BY dateColumn ASC LIMIT 1);

SELECT @lastDate as lastDate, HOUR(TIMEDIFF(dateColumn, @lastDate)) as diff, @lastDate := dateColumn, dateColumn
FROM table 
group by dateColumn 
having diff > 1
order by dateColumn ASC;
```

In some cases mysql 5.5 and 5.6 will give different results for `HAVING` clause. Above query will run good on mysql 5.5. I have created another version to run on both version similarly like this :

```
SET @lastDate := (SELECT dateColumn FROM table ORDER BY dateColumn ASC LIMIT 1);

SELECT * FROM (SELECT @lastDate as lastDate, HOUR(TIMEDIFF(dateColumn, @lastDate)) AS diff, @lastDate := dateColumn, dateColumn FROM table GROUP BY dateColumn ORDER BY dateColumn ASC) AS tbl  WHERE tbl.diff > 1;
```